# All DOM "id" attributes are missing in my Vue.js app when built and served in production mode

Tags: docker, nginx, vuejs3

When served locally (yarn, vite), my vue app works fine.

However, when built and served in production mode, **all my DOM elements are missing the "id" attribute**

As a result, document.getElementById(id) returns null all the time.
I checked the sources in the image and my dynamic ids seem to be present:

Source:

```
<div id="myId" + someUniqueId><div>
```

Result:

```
[...] {id:"myId"+unref(r),modelValue:y.value" [...]
```

I don't know where to look anymore - any ideas?

This is my docker file (if relevant)

```
FROM node:18-buster AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build-no-check #does a vite build (instead of vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build)

FROM nginx:1.23 AS final
EXPOSE 80
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/share/nginx/
COPY --from=build /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/entrypoint.sh
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/share/nginx/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: What is the actual code behind `someUniqueId`?

Comment: Mostly a String representation of an UUID. But even the static ones disappear 

Comment: Do you use a package for the UUID? Is it in `devDependecies`?

Comment: I do: "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4"

Comment: Those are TS types, not a package with functionality per-se I think.

Comment: Are you using the browser build in [crypto UUID function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID)? For me that did work fine in dev, but after building with vite, it did not work anymore. Did not spend much time on it, but went for the [uuid package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: I can also recommend [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid), works well and done by well-known people.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this has anything to do with UUIDs. All id attributes are missing, not just the dynamic ones. Also, I am pretty sure it used to work before 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you try use yarn install --frozen-lockfile but dont copy the yarn.lock.
Use COPY yarn.lock ./ right after copy package.json